# How do I keep an image in a Tumblr page from stretching?

Tags: image, tumblr, stretch

I use Tumblr as my website for my band. I'm working on the discography page and I'm trying to put album artwork into a page at a 240px by 240px ratio, but it's stretching and I'm not entirely sure how to stop it from doing that.

[Link to page](http://littleplasticstars.tumblr.com/discography)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out? The page has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your blog [customize page](http://www.tumblr.com/customize). It should look like this: [tumblr customization panel http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/803/0a8e2d3f8a7e402ca707c5c.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/803/0a8e2d3f8a7e402ca707c5c.png)
2. Find field “Add custom CSS” and paste in it this code: `#entry img { width: auto; }`